# Change legend order in ggplot when coordinates are flipped

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a very simple problem that I did not manage to solve. In the following legend, I would like to have "work" above "sleep" and keep the graph and colors unchanged (so work in blue and sleep in red).

```
  data <- data.frame(Name = rep(c("Tom","Ana"), 2),
                 Category = rep(c("sleep","work"),each=2),
                 Percentage = c(40,20,60,80))
ggplot(data, aes(fill=Category, y=Percentage, x=Name)) + 
geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity", colour="black") +
coord_flip()
```

[current graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFZz8.png)

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: tip - use geom_col instead geom_bar(stat = "identity")) (they are identical), and swap x and y aesthetic , this allows you to drop coord_flip. Makes a lot of things easier. Your plot would be `ggplot(data, aes(fill=Category, x=Percentage, y=Name)) + 
  geom_col(position="fill", colour="black")`

Answer (score 1):

Nice reprex!

You may need to set the fill colors and levels manually.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(Name = rep(c("Tom","Ana"), 2),
                   Category = rep(c("sleep","work"),each=2),
                   Percentage = c(40,20,60,80))
ggplot(data, aes(fill=Category, y=Percentage, x=Name)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity", colour="black") +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("work", "sleep"), values = c("#01BFC4", "#F8766D")) + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>